# Only update records that haven't been updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, updatemodel

When creating a record i know you can use the method

```
.first_or_create!
```

to create records that don't already exist in the model. I need to do the same for when updating a model. I have an app that runs a rake task to apply a score to a column in my model.

```
prediction.update_attributes!(score: score)
```

I only want to update the scores that have not been updated yet.

is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: It may be possible, but is it wise? It may be better to write a couple of extra lines of code to make the intention clearer. `#first_or_create!` is an awful method name IMHO.

Comment: would be interested to see an example, if theres a better way im all for it :)

Comment: `prediction.update_attributes!(score: score) unless score.present?`

Comment: I have seen Rails does a great work saving unneeded database hits. I think if you try `prediction.update_attributes!(score: score)` database won't be hit if your score is the same, isn't it? you can check your console to verify. Is this what you are asking for?

Comment: How would you know `the scores that have not been updated yet`?

Comment: i have checked in the console, i get undefined method home_score as some scores have already been updated

Comment: @AndyWaite that doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for the `try` method which will attempt to call a method on an object that is potentially `nil`.

Example:

```
>> prediction.try(:update_attributes!, :score => some_new_score)
```

If `prediction` is `nil` it will just return `nil`, not throw a `NoMethodError`. If `prediction` is an object representing an existing record, then it will call the method on the object and update its `score` attribute.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try

Comment: ah turns out not what i was looking for, sorry..still getting an undefined method home_score error

Comment: Is `home_score` an existing attribute in your object? I thought you were trying to update the `score` attribute. `try` may get around the problem of the object being `nil`, but the attribute or method still needs to exist since you're ultimately trying to call a method on your object.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with juanpastas that Rails will only save to the db if something has actually changed. IF you want to be more explicit in your code, Why not use the '.changed?' flag to save only dirty records? Look [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Dirty) for more details.